# responseJSON getting no response

Tags: json, swift, alamofire, imageshack

I am using Alamofire to try and put an image on image shack server using the [image shack API](https://code.google.com/archive/p/imageshackapi/wikis/ImageshackAPI.wiki). I am not getting a response back and get the error:

> FAILURE: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3840 "Invalid value
>   around character 0.

I have highlighted where the error is referring too in the code also:

```
        let imageName = "pano.jpg"
        let postImage = UIImage(named: imageName)
        let urlStr = "https://post.imageshack.us/upload_api.php"
        let theUrl:NSString = urlStr.stringByRemovingPercentEncoding!
        let url = NSURL(string: theUrl as String)!
        let imgData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(postImage!, 0.2)!
        let keyData = "0345CHKMad115dd32980b363be5f2d34731b8110".dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)!
        let keyJSON = "json".dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)!


Alamofire.upload(.POST, url, multipartFormData: { MultipartFormData in

                MultipartFormData.appendBodyPart(data: imgData, name: "fileupload", mimeType: "image/jpg")
                MultipartFormData.appendBodyPart(data: keyData, name: "key")
                MultipartFormData.appendBodyPart(data: keyJSON, name: "format")

            }) {encodingResult in

                switch encodingResult {
                case .Success(let upload, _, _):
                    upload.responseJSON(completionHandler: { response in

                        print(response) //ERROR HERE
                        guard let data = response.result.value
                            else{
                                print("Request failed with error data)")

                            return
                        }

                        if let info = data as? Dictionary<String, AnyObject> {
                            if let links = info["links"] as? Dictionary<String, AnyObject> {
                                if let imgLink = links["image_link"] as? String {
                                    print(imgLink)
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    })
```

I am completely lost what this problem means any help would be great.

Comment: The error message simply reveals that it's not valid JSON.

Comment: Thanks, although if I changed 'responseJSON' to 'responseString' I get back: <error id="parameter_missing">Sorry, but we've detected that unexpected data is received. Required parameter 'fileupload' is missing or your post is not multipart/form-data</error> Can you help with this? I'm not sure why this is

Comment: I'm not familiar with Alamofire at all, I was just interpreting the error message. I guess it depends on what the server actually returns.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, before passing your `url` into the function do:

```
//Convert the NSURL to a NSString
let urlString:NSString = url.absoluteString() as! NSString

//Remove Percent Encoding
let theUrl:NSString = urlString.stringByRemovingPercentEncoding()

//Place Back into NSURL
let newUrl = NSURL(string:theUrl)
```

And pass `newUrl` instead of `url`. It would be better to do this before instantiation of the original `url`, but try that and see if that helps.

**EDIT**

try this too where you are having the issue:

```
var jsonError:NSError?
let json = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(response, options: nil, error: &jsonError) as NSDictionary {

    print(json)
}
```

Comment: Thanks although I am getting error: Value of type 'NSURL'  has no member 'stringByRemovingPercentEncoding

Comment: String does have that method

Comment: Thanks, it does have that method but still the same problem and error, anything else? I've updated my code also

Comment: I updated my answer. What are you expecting back as response?

Comment: Sorry I'm a bit confused where is the new bit you've added meant to go? I am trying to get the 'print(imgLink)' to print.

Comment: Where you put `// ERROR HERE`. Put the rest of the code within that and access the response as the `json`.

Comment: ok thanks now I get line error - Variable with getter/setter cannot have an initial value

Comment: I hate swift. Is it with the `NSError`?

Comment: Anything else you think it could be?

Answer (score 0):

```
   switch encodingResult {
                    case .Success(let upload, _,_):
                        upload.responseJSON(completionHandler: {response in

                            if let data = response.result.value as? Dictionary<String, AnyObject>{

                                if let links = data["links"] as? Dictionary<String, AnyObject> {
                                    if let imgLink = links["image_link"] as? String {
                                        print(imgLink)
                                    }
                                }
                            }


                        })
                    case .Failure(let error):
                        print(error)
                    }
```